# Jersey JPA - 500 only when returning result sets from SP with parameters

Tags: java, rest, jpa, stored-procedures, jersey

I am using Jersey and JPA. My queries will work as expected if not using a stored procedure with parameters. If the stored procedure uses parameters the data from the query to the DB returns perfectly. On debug I can see the data in the List the whole way back to the return statement on the controller then I get a 500. (On debug I receive the message class not found, this is throwing me a little as without the parameters everything works fine). Any help would be much appreciated.

Repo Code

```
package com.aeolos.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;

import com.aeolos.listener.LocalEntityManagerFactory;
import com.aeolos.model.Employee;
import com.aeolos.model.Callback;


public class EmployeeRepo implements IEmployeeRepo {

EntityManager em = LocalEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

@Override
public Employee getEmployee(long id) {
    try {
        Employee test = new Employee();
        test = em.find(Employee.class, id);
        return test;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

@Override
public List<Employee> getStoredEmployee() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetAllEmployees", Employee.class);
        List<Employee> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

@Override
public Employee save(Employee employee) {
    try{
        em.persist(employee);
        em.flush();
        return employee;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

@Override
public List<Callback> getAllCallbacks() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetAllCallbacks", Callback.class);
        List<Callback> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}


@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Callback> getCallbacksByDateTime(String cbdate, String cbtime) {
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetCallbacksByDateTime");
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramDate", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramTime", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter("paramDate", cbdate);
        query.setParameter("paramTime", cbtime);
        query.execute();
        List<Callback> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

@Override
public Callback getCallback(long id) {
    try {
        Callback result = new Callback();
        result = em.find(Callback.class, id);
        return result;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

@Override
public Callback SaveCallback(Callback callback) {
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(callback);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return callback;
    } finally {         
        em.close();
    }
}

}
```

Service Code

```
package com.aeolos.service;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

 import com.aeolos.dao.EmployeeRepo;
 import com.aeolos.model.Callback;
 import com.aeolos.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeService implements IEmployeeService{

private EmployeeRepo repo;

public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepo repo){
    this.repo = repo;
}

@Override
public Employee read(long id) {     
    return repo.getEmployee(id);
}  

@Override
public List<Employee> store() {  
    return repo.getStoredEmployee();
}

public List<Callback> GetAllCallbacks() {
    return repo.getAllCallbacks();
}

public List<Callback> GetCallbacksByDateTime(String cbdate, String cbtime) {
    return repo.getCallbacksByDateTime(cbdate, cbtime);
}

@Override
public Callback GetCallback(long id) {      
    return repo.getCallback(id);
} 

@Override
public Callback SaveCallback(Callback callback) {       
    return repo.SaveCallback(callback);
} 

}
```

Controller Code (Please note the commented out Method works fine (SP without parameters)

```
package com.aeolos.controller;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  

import com.aeolos.dao.EmployeeRepo;
import com.aeolos.model.Callback;
import com.aeolos.service.EmployeeService;

@Path("/callback") 
public class CallbackController {

private EmployeeRepo repo = new EmployeeRepo();
private EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService(repo);

 //    @GET
//    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
//    public List<Callback> store() {  
//      return service.GetAllCallbacks();
//    }

@GET  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public List<Callback> read(@QueryParam("paramdate") String cbdate, @QueryParam("paramtime") String cbtime) {   
    List<Callback> callbacks = service.GetCallbacksByDateTime(cbdate, cbtime);
    return callbacks;
}

@GET  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
@Path("{id}")  
public Callback read(@PathParam("id") long id) {    
    return service.GetCallback(id);
} 

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public Callback save(
        @FormParam("employeenumber") String employeenumber,
        @FormParam("customer") String customer,
        @FormParam("mobile") String mobile,
        @FormParam("landline") String landline,
        @FormParam("cbtype") String cbtype,
        @FormParam("cbreason") String cbreason,
        @FormParam("cbdate") String cbdate,
        @FormParam("cbtime") String cbtime
        ) {  
    Callback callback = new Callback();
    callback.setEmployeenumber(employeenumber);
    callback.setCustomer(customer);
    callback.setMobile(mobile);
    callback.setLandline(landline);
    callback.setCbtype(cbtype);
    callback.setCbreason(cbreason);
    callback.setCbdate(cbdate);
    callback.setCbtime(cbtime);
    return service.SaveCallback(callback);
}
}
```

Comment: If you include the stack trace in your question, we can help you understand what it means. If you do not include the stack trace, you make it really hard to help you. Actually, if you read the stack trace yourself, you can probably either figure out what is going on, or ask a much more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem, I had forgotten to add Callback.class to the createStoredProcedureQuery call, which led to the resultset not being mapped to a known entity.